# Retrive average rating and total number of rating for each and every product in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, e-commerce

I'm trying to build a product rating system in Laravel. I have two different tables `product` and `review` where all products and reviews data are stored.

`product` Table has fields like **id**, **name**, **price**, etc. 
`review` table has fields like **id**, **product_id**, **rating**, etc.

One product can have many reviews/ratings. I need to fetch all products with each product's average rating and total rating. I can fetch all products like the below:

```
$product = Product::all();
```

but how can I get average rating and total rating(count) also for each and every product? Every answer will be very helpful for me and ‍admirable.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using query builder since I don't know your Models.

```
$productId = 1; // example product id

$ratingCount = DB::table('review')
->where('product_id', $productId)
->count();

$averageRating = DB::table('review')
->where('product_id', $productId)
->avg('rating');

$data = [
"ratingCount" => $ratingCount,
"averageRating" => $averageRating 
];

return $data;
```

Edit

Our you can get each product average rating in one data with this:

```
$products = DB::table('product')
    ->leftJoin('review', 'review.product_id', '=', 'product.id')
    ->select(['product.*',
        DB::raw('AVG(review.rating) as ratingsAverage')
        ])
    ->get();
```

Hope this answer work and help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this will work for a single product only and also when I know the product_id. But I need this for all the products from the Product table. When I retrieve all products data from the product table, the average rating and total rating should include with that. So that I can show all the products with their rating into a single page. Is there any way to do that with a single eloquent query or query builder?

Comment: I got your point. What is relation name between Product Model and Review? I assume it named `reviews` with hasMany relation. Then try this ```$products = Product::with(['reviews'])
    ->leftJoin('review', 'review.product_id', '=', 'product.id')
    ->select(['product.*',
        DB::raw('AVG(review.rating) as ratingsAverage')
        ])
    ->get(); ```